# How do I get a ZTE MF651 USB Modem working?

Tags: networking, usb-modem, usb-modeswitch

At first, my modem was only detected by lsusb. It shows like this:

> Bus 002 Device 004: ID 19d2:0146 ONDA Communication S.p.A.

Next, I installed usb-modeswitch and created a config file:

```
vi /etc/udev/rules.d/zte_mf651.rules
```

then filled it with:

```
SYSFS{idVendor}=="19d2", SYSFS{idProduct}=="0146", RUN+="/usr/bin/eject %k", OPTIONS+="last_rule"
```

Now my modem is detected, dmesg shows ttyACM0 and ttyACM1.

After configuring My Provider, it shows on the top menu bar, under the network connection icon.
When I clicked it, the modem was connected, but there seems no internet connection..
it can't access internet via browser. While it works fine on windows.

So, How to enable/optimize the internet connection?
Is there any specific driver for this device on Ubuntu? 
Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your modem support Ethernet ports. If yes, can you please try with that and let us know.

Comment: how to check that my modem support eth port?

Comment: I hope you can recognize RJ45 female pin, if not then search for it in google and see how does it looks. Then check the back side of your modem for similar port. If it is there then your modem supports eth port.

Comment: oops, it seems my modem doesn't support eth port.. it's just a simple usb dongle type modem

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in ModemManager. You should manually start DHCP client AFTER connection with NetworkManager, just type in the command prompt:

```
sudo dhclient usb0
```

Instead of UDEV rules you can use usb_modeswitch utility, see this thread: http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/bb/viewtopic.php?t=889